# Curl in PHP to XMLHttpRequest Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, curl, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to convert this CURL in PHP to XML Javascript, but can't find the equivalent of some parameters

So I have this in my PHP :

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, 
    array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $transaction,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Connection: keep-live",
            "content-type: application/json"
        ),
    )
);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

and need to convert them to XMLHttpRequest in Javascript. I've got this so far:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.responseType = 'json';
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader('Connection', 'keep-live');
xhr.send(transaction);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {};
```

I was wondering how to use these :

```
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
```

with XMLHttpRequest

Comment: You shouldn't need them. Is there anything in the xhr request not working as you'd expected?

Comment: P.s. why not use modern fetch() instead of legacy XHR?

Comment: @ADyson several of those values cannot be set in Fetch

Comment: @mplungjan i don't think they can be set in XHR either can they? There's nothing in the XHR code the OP has written so far that can't be done in fetch(), certainly

Comment: Max redirects and timeouts etc?